# Firebase A/B Testing - How to run mutually exclusive experiments

Tags: firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I want to run two experiments for my app using Firebase A/B Testing with Remote Config. The two test audiences must be mutually exclusive in order not to affect the results of each other.

Each experiment will use a different non-overlapping set of Remote Config parameters.

Does Firebase allow running such experiments?

The following options do not work for me:
1.runing experiments serially
2.combining experiments into a single multi-variant experiment

I tried to run two experiments, using three Remote Config parameters in each experiment, where one parameter was shared between the two experiments, and the other two were unique. My goal was to completely avoid audience overlap. However, in the end, the audiences still overlapped in terms of the two unique parameters, while not overlapping for the shared third parameter.

So I didn't get what I wanted.